# How do you unlock Dry Bowser in Mario Kart Wii?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

I have all the characters in Mario Kart Wii but I'm missing Dry Bowser.  How do I get him?

Answer (score 10):

You need to finish all Grand Prix Cups on the 150cc difficulty with at least one star rank in each cup.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to unlock Dry Bowser is to play 4350 races ([source](https://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart_Wii#Drivers)).